# Form validation problem with CodeIgniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I have this view:

```
   <?php echo form_open(); ?>

<?php echo form_input('username', '', ''); ?>

<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

and this controller method:

```
function test() {


        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($username, 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {

            echo 'Tada!';

        }

        $this->load->view('test');        

    }
```

but when I leave the username field blank, nothing happens. However, if I type in something in it will tell me the field is required. I've downloaded and given CI a fresh install almost ten times now, trying to load with and without different helpers etc. It's becoming really frustrating,  please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]');
```

Comment: @Melanie: Do you *at least* realize your mistake here? The first parameter needs to be the input's `name`, not the value of what was $_POSTed. This would explain your symptoms exactly. Please reconsider this answer, and make sure you're reading the user guide to avoid these types of mistakes. It doesn't matter if you switch computers or reinstall CI if you aren't following [the instructions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules).

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the first parameter of set_rules, which is the field name.

The **$username** you're passing is basically setting the field name to validate as whatever the user puts in the input field. If you were to type 'username' into the input box, you'd see that your form validates.

Change the line

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($username, 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is the problem of this line

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
```

If you leave it blank it basically send back to the controller itself and calling the construct and index function only. In this case your function dealing with form processing is "test()"

try this

```
<?php echo form_open('yourControllerName/test'); ?> //test is the function dealing with
```

if it is not working try on this

```
<?php echo form_open('test'); ?>
```